# Alt/Enter to import missing classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I'm running the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html and on the page titled "Starting Another Activity", section titled "Build an Intent"

After following the instructions

> In MainActivity.java, add the code shown below to `sendMessage()`,

*MainActivity.java* looks like this:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then the instructions say to press *Alt/Enter* to import the missing classes. After pressing *Alt/Enter* the code looks like this (the only change is in the imports):

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The studio then says to press *Alt/Enter* again (I think to resolve `EXTRA_MESSAGE`). So I did. That put up a dialog to "Create constant field 'EXTRA_MESSAGE'". But I don't know what value to give it.

The first press of *Alt/Enter* does not produce the expected result. The tutorial says the imports should look like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Now I'm perplexed as to what to do next.

Can someone comment on what may be missing from the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to have String constant like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

You should use this constant as a key to put and to retrieve the value.

Also remove this line:

```
import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
```

Comment: My error, the tutorial said to enter the EXTRA_MESSAGE line but the bold text did not stand out for me and I didn't notice it.